# If you want to return a member by reference, what is the best way to define it?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble choosing between two options. If you want to have a function returning a class member by reference, how should the class member be defined ?

- `MemberClass m_member` ?
- `MemberClass* m_member` ?

Let's say m_member is a member of type MemberClass(*) of the class MyClass.

If I do the first option, I have this :

```
.h
MemberClass &getMember(){return m_member;} //getter to the member, returns by reference
MemberClass m_member;

.cpp
//MyClass constructor
MyClass::MyClass(QObject * parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    m_member(MemberClass(this)),
    ...
```

Second option :

```
.h
MemberClass &getMember(){return *m_member;} //getter to the member, returns by reference
MemberClass* m_member;

.cpp
//MyClass constructor
MyClass::MyClass(QObject * parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    m_member = new MemberClass(this);
    ...
```

What is the best way of doing that ?
Plus, I realised that with the first option I was forced into implementing operator= and copy constructor for MemberClass, why is that ?

**EDIT**

- I want m_member to live outside the class.
- MemberClass is in fact a Controller (like in the MVC Design Pattern)
  and I have to use it many times in the code.
- MyClass is in charge of instanciating the    Controller of class
  MemberClass and some others and provide a getter to their instance
- m_member cannot be NULL
- it would be great if m_member was unique, to do that I put its constructor to protected and registered MyClass as a friend class

Comment: do you want m_member to live outside the class?

Comment: It may be better to think about operations on MyClass such that the internals are never exposed like this.

Comment: IMHO avoid pointers until you know you are going to need them.  You can return  reference to a class member that has automatic storage(`MemberClass m_member`) just fine.

Comment: I want m_member to live outside the class. MemberClass is in fact a Controler (like in the MVC Design Pattern) and I have to use it many times in the code.

Comment: On the other side, Qt consistently uses pointers with `QObject` and `QWidget` derivatives.

Comment: So you want the member to be able to outlive the object the member is from?

Comment: What do you mean by outlive ? Live outside MyClass or live after MyClass is destructed ? I edited the post to add more information.

Comment: @ElevenJune Yes.  If the object is destroyed to do still want the object returned by `getMember` to be valid?

Comment: @NathanOliver : Yes I do. I want the MemberClass to die with ~MyClass, but I want access to MemberClass from other classes (GUI asking to update the datas for example).

Comment: Q: "If the object is destroyed to do still want the object returned by getMember to be valid? ".  A: "Yes I do. I want the MemberClass to die with ~MyClass". So, you're answering yes and no at the same time? Anyway, I don't see any concept of "best way" between having a member instance vs a member pointer. Either you need one, or you need the other. And if you think you need a pointer... then you probably _actually_ need a reference.

Comment: @underscore_d : I do want the return to be valid, so when MyClass is destructed I don't want to be able to access m_member anymore. Also, as long as MyClass lives, I want access to m_member with a valid value.

Comment: Well, of _course_ when an instance is destructed, you can't access a member, either directly or via a getter! Back to while the parent _is_ alive: Do you want the getter to return a reference to an internal instance (lifetime constrained with parent), or return a copy (lifetime can be extended by caller)? Then return by reference or value respectively. Pointers don't appear to be required in any case.

Comment: I'm sure I want a return by reference and not a copy. MemberClass is not supposed to be instanciated multiple time but I don't think the Singleton Pattern is the best way to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually depends on whether your member can be `NULL`. If it can not - use first option, if it can - use second one. Also in you first case you should use `m_member(this)`, not `m_member(MemberClass(this))`.

Also consider adding `const` getter which can be used on `const`-objects:

```
const MemberClass &getMember() const {
    return m_member;
}
```

Also note, that your second code is pretty dangerous. Try to avoid raw pointers when possible and use `std::unique_ptr` when necessary.

**EDIT**:

If `m_member` should be just a reference to some `MemberClass` than you should never use first option as it is going to create another instance of the `MemberClass`. In this case use reference `MemberClass& m_member` if `MyClass` is guaranteed to live longer than `MemberClass` and reference should not be changed to point to another instance (because you can't do that with C++ references). Consider using `std::shared_ptr<MemberClass>` in other cases.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I don't want it to be null, so maybe the second option is better. Thank you also for the correct way of instanciating it. I don't know yet If I will need the const but I suppose it is better to put it now and remove it later than the contrary.

Comment: @ElevenJune: The FIRST if it can't be nullptr.

Comment: The reference could be great yeah. What would be the advantage against option one ? Not being able to change it ?

Comment: Switching to dynamic allocation just so you can "NULL" out an object is an awful approach. `boost::optional`, hellooo! Also the real answer is that this has absolutely nothing to do with whether a member function will return a reference to the object so it's entirely moot.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit soon to be `std::optional`, hooray!

Comment: @underscore_d: w00t!

Comment: @Pixelchemist :  Yeah sorry, the first !

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, yeah, but I just didn't want to point to something that is not in standard. And there are cases when you can't use external libraries so you have to use what you can. I agree that pointers should be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a raw pointer or having an automatic object I suggest you use a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).  If you have an automatic storage member like your first example you will not be able to keep it alive after the class is destroyed and allow the object and whatever has a handle to the member to modify the same object.  If you use a pointer you can transfer ownership but know you class gets more complicated as you have to implement the rule of 3 and you have to keep track of who has a handle.

If you use a `std::shared_ptr` then you can return that pointer by value from `getMember` and now whoever got that handle shares in the ownership of the member.  If the object is destroyed then whoever still has handle still has a valid object as there are still instances of the pointer in your code.  If all of the things who had a handle to the member are gone and then you object is destroyed the pointer will be deleted for you as the last holder of the pointer was destroyed.  Now there is no more manual memory management, the default constructors will work and you have expressed your intent on how the ownership of member should behave.  That's a win-win-win.

Comment: I still can't _quite_ figure out whether the OP really wants the contained object to be capable of outliving its 'parent', but if they do, this is of course the correct answer and well explained.

Comment: Thank you for your very interesting answer ! Right now it is not really my priority but it could be very useful later, I'll look more into that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first way is the better way of doing it, as it'll allow you to avoid allocating memory on the heap and dealing with the cleanup of that pointer. In addition, you get to reap the small performance benefit of using member initialization list. However, in both cases you have to face the possibility of the reference to the member variable living longer than the object, which can cause issues.

As for why you were forced to implement operator= and copy constructor, I'm unsure, but unless you declare your constructor as 'explicit', it might want to force you to deal with situations where someone says:

```
QObject* q = new QObject;
MyClass myObj = q;
```

As this would cause an implicit conversion.

In C++11, you might be able to delete the operator= and copy constructor instead of defining them though:

```
MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = delete;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the operator= and copy constructor part, it seems the problem was the instanciation, I was doing m_member(MemberClass(this)) instead of m_member;

Comment: Ah, that makes very much sense now that you mention it. Good catch!